# object type is showing as an empty array in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, actionresult

I am migrating from .netcore 2.1 to .net 6. I have an endpoint that has a return type of Task I have a class that has properties of type object.
And after some checks I am returning an ok result of my object  i.e `return Ok(myObj);`
This is working without any problems in .netcore 2.1 but in .net6 the object properties are returning empty arrays for some reason.
I created a new app directly in .net 6 and tried to replicate the issue to see if it was some mistake I made while migrating or not but it seems that it doesn't work either. The new project looks like this :

```
 [HttpGet("test")]   
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var features = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
    {
        { "Foo", true },
        { "Bar", false }
    };
    var settings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "font-size", "16-px" },
        { "showOnStartUp", "no" }
    };
    var resp = new Result()
    {
        InnerDto = new InnerDto()
        {
            Foo = BuildObject(features.Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(f.Key, f.Value)).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)),
            Bar = BuildObject(settings.Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(f.Key, f.Value)).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value))
        },
        S = "Test"
    };
    

    return Ok(resp);
}


private static object BuildObject(Dictionary<string, object> foo)
{

    var objects = foo.Select(f => new
    {
        Key = f.Key,
        Value = SetSettingsValueBasedOnType(f)
    }).ToList();

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("{");

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        string val;
        var obj = objects[i];
        if (bool.TryParse(obj.Value.ToString(), out var parsedVal))
        {
            val = obj.Value.ToString()!.ToLower();
        }
        else
        {
            val = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.Value);
        }

        var line = $@"""{obj.Key}"":{val}";
        sb.AppendLine(line);
        if (i < objects.Count - 1)
        {
            sb.Append(',');
        }
    }
    sb.AppendLine("}");
    var featuresObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sb.ToString());
    return featuresObj!;
}

private static object SetSettingsValueBasedOnType(KeyValuePair<string, object> bar)
{

    object val;
    if (bool.TryParse(bar.Value.ToString(), out var parseVal))
    {
        val = parseVal;
    }
    else
    {
        val = bar.Value;
    }

    return val;

}
}

   public class Result
{
   public string S { get; set; }
  public InnerDto InnerDto { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDto
{
    public object Foo { get; set; }
    public object Bar { get; set; }
}
```

the logic is working to the last line before the return as you can see here:
[image]
and the response I'm getting is like this:
[image]

What is making this work on .netcore 2.1 and not on .net 6?

Comment: Changed the Serializer used by ASP.Net? If i recall correctly the default changed from JSON.Net to System.Text.Json.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: I am using NewtonsoftJSON package all over the project to Serilize and Deserilize, I changed it in this mini project and used System.Text.Json serilizer and it worked. Does this mean I need to change  every single serilize and deserilize proccess all over the application? is there no way to make newtonsoftJson work ?

Comment: You need to add Json.Net to your setup if you want to use that. So somewhere where you build your host for asp.net you need to add a `AddNewtonsoftJson()` so that Asp.Net itself uses NewtonSoft.

Comment: @Ralf Thank you, this seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `Newtonsoft.JSON`, it is fine, just add serialized object to your object.

Change this

```
return Ok(resp);
```

to

```
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp, Formatting.Indented));
```

Now we know it works, we could add it globally to all controllers by doing this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

In this case, you might need to install the following package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.13" />
```

Then this will also work `return Ok(resp);`

And here is your output:

[image]

Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.newtonsoftjsonmvcbuilderextensions.addnewtonsoftjson?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: thank you, the problem actually was  that NewtonsoftJson converts object to JObject while System.Text.Json Serializer converts it to JsonElement and thats where it breaks. 
It was a matter of refactoring all the code so it uses System.Text.Json or use Newtonsoft as the default Serilizer.